# I topped up my oyster using cash and forgot to retap

Tags: money, london, refunds, tfl

I tapped my oyster to top up put in cash and forgot to retap.  The money did not go onto my oyster £10 what can I do?

Comment: How long ago was this? And is it easy for you to get back to the station where this happened?

Comment: I'm guessing that without a receipt you'd have no chance of claiming anything. Try talking to someone at a manned ticket counter.

Comment: Did you call up Oyster helpline, they should be able to help and provide you with the options.

Answer (score 4):

[According to this independent oyster guide](http://www.oyster-rail.org.uk/topping-up/), in case of a top-up by payment card (credit or debit) if the second tap fails then the payment will be authorised but it won't be debited, and you should see the payment authorisation disappear from your card statement in the following days:

> If you pay by card then the transaction will be authorised after you enter your PIN.  If you forget to touch again to get the top-up added then this authorisation will remain and may appear as if the money has been taken.  It hasn’t, and the authorisation will drop off 2-3 business days later when TfL will have failed to charge the debit to your bank.

Since you forgot to re-tap after topping up by cash I am afraid there's not much you can do to claim a refund. Moreover I assume you don't have a receipt either, since these, along with change, are released after the second tap. Your best bet would probably be to contact the Oyster helpline at `0343 222 1234` or [using the online enquiry form](https://custserv.tfl.gov.uk/icss_csip/ZCreateRequestChangeRelatesTo.do?newTab=CA_15309) and ask, or to ask someone at a a manned ticket office in any station.